# How to loop material node animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I animated parameters of the shader nodes in Cycles, now I need to loop this animation, but I can't find those keyframes in the graph editor.

[image]

Is it possible to see those keyframes in the graph editor?
Is there any other way to loop such animation?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to select the node..and then you'll see it. Or uncheck the "Only include channels of selected Objects/Data" in the header of the Graph editor next to the ghost and safeguard ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the keyframes in the Graph editor select the object that has the keyframes.

To make a loop:

Press N to access the modifiers tab int he Graph editor. Then create a cycle.

That will create a loop for the keyframes automatically.

[image]

If you want to interrupt the cycle or make it start at a particular frame, play with the values for the Before and Ater.

A different way to do the same is using the Channel Extrapolation mode and set it to cycle.

[image]