# How do I loop location values?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, node-editor

I made this wallpaper type animation and I used *Noise* and *Bump* nodes to make the floor look like flowing water. I added a mapping node to move around the detail and make it look like its flowing.

Its supposed to be a wallpaper but the problem is I cant make a loop.

I cant find a value I can add at the end of the animation to make it look like its going on forever. Anyone got any ideas how to make it into a loop?

[image: These are the nodes I used]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135437/how-to-make-tileable-procedural-noise-texture

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111066/how-to-loop-material-node-animation

Comment: 23.040-4.190 tge result number is the starting looping point that you can loop using location